# Could anyone tell me why the program call abort() in the try block?

Tags: c++

The program below compiles successfully, yet it fails to run and call the abort() function which throws a message alerting that "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contace the application's support team for more information.", Why so?

```
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>

using std::string;
using std::endl;
using std::cout;

class ThrowException{

    private:
        string msg;
        int b;
    public:
        ThrowException(string m="Unknown exception",int factor=0) throw(string);        //A

};

ThrowException::ThrowException(string m, int f) throw(string):msg(m),b(f){                 //B
    if(b==1)
        throw "b=1 not allowed.";
}

int main(){

    try{
        ThrowException a("There's nothing wrong.", 1);
    }catch(string e){
        cout<<"The address of e in catch block is "<<&e<<endl;
    }    

}
```

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 7):

On this line:

```
throw "b=1 not allowed."
```

you're actually throwing a `const char*`. If you change it to:

```
throw std::string("b=1 not allowed.")
```

or change the catch block (and the corresponding `throw` qualifiers) to:

```
}catch(const char* e){
```

it will work

Comment: Wouldn't there be any implicit type conversion?

Comment: @JDein No, because the compiler can't know you wanted that to be a `std::string`; you might've actually wanted to throw a `const char*` there. You get the same thing if you have two `foo` methods, one taking a `const char*` and one taking a `std::string`, and you call `foo("bar");` -- it's going to call the `const char*` version